# java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem with s:selectItems

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="reportType" style="width:175px" value="#{pageDemoSearchBean.status}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pageDemoSearchBean.vehicleStatus}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I am using JSF 1.2

This lines of code throws a classCastException

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

Provided that replacing "value" by "itemValue" in f:selectItems tag is giving another exception which tells that

> itemValue is incorrect for selectItems according to TLD

Comment: When using JSF 1.x, look for JSF 1.x answers/examples/resources, not for JSF 2.x answers/examples/resources.

Comment: please show us the code where  you import the lib in the jsp page

Comment: Please ignore above nosense comment of Si mo. There's no means of a JSP import here.

Comment: Your method `pageDemoSearchBean.vehicleStatus` should return `List<SelectItem>` instead of `List<String>`

Answer (score 2):

In JSF 1.x, it is not possible to provide a `List<T>` as `<f:selectItems value>`. It only supports [`List<javax.faces.model.SelectItem>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html).

Here's a kickoff example of proper usage, copypasted from our [selectonemenu](/questions/tagged/selectonemenu) [tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) (which is written with JSF 2.x in mind, so take into account that some examples won't work for the jurassic JSF 1.x):

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

```
private String selectedItem; // +getter +setter
private List<SelectItem> availableItems; // +getter (no setter necessary)

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    availableItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    availableItems.add(new SelectItem("foo", "Foo label"));
    availableItems.add(new SelectItem("bar", "Bar label"));
    availableItems.add(new SelectItem("baz", "Baz label"));
}
```